# Хочу сделать одиночную нажатие кнопки мыши в pygame

Tags: python, pygame, мышь

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()

WIDTH,HEIGHT = 800,600
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
BG = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('images/bg.jpeg'), (WIDTH , HEIGHT)).convert()
pinky = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('images/pinky.png'), (60,120))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
aim = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('images/aim.png'), (75,75))

class Baloons:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.img = pinky
        self.rects = pinky.get_rect()

    def draw(self, window):
        window.blit(self.img, (self.x, self.y))

    def move(self, speed):
        self.y -= speed


def main():
    run = True
    FPS = 60
    speed = 3
    baloons = []
    scores = 0
    lost = 0
    lose = False
    wave = 5

    def redraw():
        SCREEN.blit(BG, (0,0))

        # Рендерим тут, так как scores не обновится
        scores_font = pygame.font.SysFont('Roboto Mono', 40)
        lost_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)
        scores_render = scores_font.render(f'Scores: {scores}', True, 'black')
        losts_render = lost_font.render(f'Пропущенно {lost}/10 шариков', True, 'red')
        SCREEN.blit(scores_render,(10,10))
        SCREEN.blit(losts_render,(WIDTH-losts_render.get_width()-10,15))

        record_open = open('record.txt')
        record_show = record_open.read().strip()
        if scores > int(record_show):
            record_write = open('record.txt', 'w')
            record_write.write(str(scores))
        record_render = scores_font.render(f'Record: {record_show}', True, 'Black')
        SCREEN.blit(record_render,(10,scores_render.get_height() + 10))

        for baloon in baloons:
            baloon.draw(SCREEN)

        mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        SCREEN.blit(aim,(mouse_x-37 , mouse_y-35))

        pygame.display.flip()

    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        redraw()
        if len(baloons) == 0:
            wave+= 2
            for i in range(wave):
                baloon = Baloons(random.randint(50,WIDTH - 100), random.randint(700,1500))
                baloons.append(baloon)

        mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        for baloon in baloons:
            # mouse[0] = x, mouse[1] = y.Бір біріне азайтамыз, коллизияны табу ушин
            if baloon.rects.collidepoint(mouse_x - baloon.x,
                             mouse_y - baloon.y) and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
                baloons.remove(baloon)
                scores += 10
            if baloon.y < -100:
                baloons.remove(baloon)
                lost += 1
            baloon.move(speed)

        if lost >= 10:
            run = False
            continue

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
def main_menu():
    run = True
    while run:
        SCREEN.blit(BG,(0,0))
        start_font = pygame.font.SysFont('Raleway', 100)
        start_render = start_font.render('Играть', True, 'Yellow')
        SCREEN.blit(start_render,(WIDTH/2 - start_render.get_width() + 100, HEIGHT/2 - start_render.get_height()))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                main()
        pygame.display.flip()
main_menu()
```

Comment: я пробовал и с pygame.mouse,get_pressed()[0]. Но в обеих случаях они стираются как ластик, если зажать XD

Answer (score 0):

````py
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
BG = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('images/bg.jpeg'), (WIDTH, HEIGHT)).convert()
pinky = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('images/pinky.png'), (60, 120))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
aim = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('images/aim.png'), (75, 75))


class Baloons:
    def init(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.img = pinky
        self.rects = pinky.get_rect()

    def draw(self, window):
        window.blit(self.img, (self.x, self.y))

    def move(self, speed):
        self.y -= speed


def main():
    run = True
    FPS = 60
    speed = 3
    baloons = []
    scores = 0
    lost = 0
    lose = False
    wave = 5

    def redraw():
        SCREEN.blit(BG, (0, 0))

        # Рендерим тут, так как scores не обновится
        scores_font = pygame.font.SysFont('Roboto Mono', 40)
        lost_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)
        scores_render = scores_font.render(f'Scores: {scores}', True, 'black')
        losts_render = lost_font.render(f'Пропущенно {lost}/10 шариков', True, 'red')
        SCREEN.blit(scores_render, (10, 10))
        SCREEN.blit(losts_render, (WIDTH - losts_render.get_width() - 10, 15))

        record_open = open('record.txt')
        record_show = record_open.read().strip()
        if scores > int(record_show):
            record_write = open('record.txt', 'w')
            record_write.write(str(scores))
        record_render = scores_font.render(f'Record: {record_show}', True, 'Black')
        SCREEN.blit(record_render, (10, scores_render.get_height() + 10))

        for baloon in baloons:
            baloon.draw(SCREEN)

    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        redraw()
        pygame.display.update()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:  # Left mouse button
                    mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    for baloon in baloons:
                        if baloon.rects.collidepoint(mouse_x, mouse_y):
                            baloons.remove(baloon)
                            scores += 1

        if len(baloons) < wave:
            baloon = Baloons(random.randint(0, WIDTH - 60), HEIGHT)
            baloons.append(baloon)

        for baloon in baloons:
            baloon.move(speed)
            if baloon.y < -120:
                baloons.remove(baloon)
                lost += 1

        if lost >= 10:
            lose = True
            run = False

    pygame.quit()


if __name__ == "main":
    main()```
````

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Почему надо ставить в конце if __name__ == 'main'?.Я новичок по пайтон, так что не понимаю.И почему то после того как ты убрал нижние пробелы в init то перестало работать.А после того как поставил, то коллизия не получается :(

Answer (score -1):

Пример кода:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            # Левая кнопка мыши нажата
            print("Левая кнопка мыши нажата")
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == 1:
            # Левая кнопка мыши отпущена
            print("Левая кнопка мыши отпущена")
            
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: А с нынешним кодом?

Comment: А вопрос задать нормальный? И уберите свою простыню, её никто не будет запускать.